# How to get number of cells in LibreOfficeCalc workspace using COM-object?

Tags: lua, com, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to write a script in Lua that can open the required file for LibreOfficeCalc, find the required sheet in it, and count the number of cells in the working range. I was able to get the desired sheet this way:

```
self._myLOCdoc = luacom.CreateObject("com.sun.star.ServiceManager")
self._desktop = self._myLOCdoc:createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop")
self._workbook = self._desktop:loadComponentFromURL("file:///" .. file_path, "_blank", 0, {ReadOnly = false})
self._worksheet = _workbook:getSheets():getByIndex(0) --Yes, I'm sure I'm getting the right sheet because I was able to check its name using :getName()
```

But what to do next? If I were using MSExcel, I would do something like this:

```
local user_range = self._worksheet.UsedRange

--...

local cell_cnt = user_range.Cells.count
```

But how to do the same with LibreOffice? I tried using self._worksheet:getRangeAddress(), but I'm not sure I got what I needed and couldn't get the cells from the result.

Answer (score 1):

If I were writing this in BASIC, I would do it like this:

```
  _worksheet = oSheets.getByIndex(0)
  oCursor = _worksheet.createCursor()
  oCursor.gotoEndOfUsedArea(False)
  oCursor.gotoStartOfUsedArea(True)
  nCountCells = oCursor.getRows().getCount() * oCursor.getColumns().getCount()
```

Can you translate this into LUA?

Comment: Yes, I was able to translate it. But I got the number 1. And I expected 143.

Comment: That is, in your test sheet only cell M11 (or K13) was filled in and you wanted to know the number of cells in the range A1:M11 (or A1:K13)? No problem! Just remove the line with `gotoStartOfUsedArea(True)` and change False to True in `gotoEndOfUsedArea()`

Comment: There are a lot of cells filled in the document. The last completed one is M11. Unfortunately, the proposed changes did not help. cursor:getRows():getCount() and cursor:getColumns():getCount() are always equal to 1. I don't understand how it works =(

Comment: I don't understand why this doesn't work. When we move the newly created cursor .gotoEndOfUsedArea(True), the result is a range of cells from A1 to the last filled one. `cursor:getRows():getCount()` should return 11, `cursor:getColumns():getCount()` should return 13, and their product should give 143. It would be better if we move this discussion to [**another resource**](https://ask.libreoffice.org/c/english/) - here in the comments we we cannot find a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was given a solution here: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-get-number-of-cells-in-libreofficecalc-workspace-using-com-object/96360/5

The answer suggested by JohnSUN is correct, but that's not how "true" and "false" work in Lua. You need to write it like this:

```
local cursor = self._worksheet:createCursor()
        cursor:gotoEndOfUsedArea(1)
        local nCountCells = cursor:getRows():getCount() * cursor:getColumns():getCount() --143
        local RCount = cursor:getRows():getCount() --11
        local CCount = cursor:getColumns():getCount() --13
```

Comment: Of course, it was also JohnSUN in the other post who suggested to try `1` in Lua, which is the solution shown here.